# How do I use a string split in object initialiser syntax (foreach)?

Tags: c#, foreach, many-to-many

How can I use a foreach loop to represent the object initializer syntax?

```
public class Post
{
public int PostId { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Content { get; set; }
public ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag
{
public int TagId { get; set; }
public Tag Tag { get; set; }
public int PostId { get; set; }
public Post Post { get; set;}
}

public class Tag
{
public int TagId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; set }
}

public IActionResult Add(NewPostModel model)
{
    return new Post()
    {
        Title = model.Title,

        Content = model.Content,
```

I would like to use a foreach loop with a string.Split(new char[]{ ' ' } to represent each tag input I do.

```
 PostTags = new List<PostTag> ()
        {
            new PostTag ()
            {
                Tag = new Tag (){ Name = Name};
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `something.Split().Select(x=>new Tag(){Name=x}).ToList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a property on `NewPostModel model` with a space delimited set of tags, with the name `SomeStringWithTags`, you can use the result of the `string.Split` as a basis for a Select projection to return a `PostTag` projection for each string:

```
return new Post
{
    Title = model.Title,
    Content = model.Content,
    PostTags = model.SomeStringWithTags.Split(new []{' '})
          .Select(s => 
          {
             new PostTag
             {
                 Tag = new Tag { Name = s }
             }
          }
          .ToList() // .. needed because of the `ICollection`
 };
```

i.e. You won't actually need an explcit `foreach` at all.

Comment: would something like this work for SomeStringWithTags? List<string> tags

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the comment? SomeStringWithTags obviously is a string. PostTags could be an enumerable if no further changes to the collection are required.